# Show/Hide Form not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a button that when you click on it, it shows a small box with a newsletter sign up form in it.

I've written my JavaScript but it doesn't seem to work.

I'd appreciate any pointers you could give me on why this isn't working.

```
<script>
  function setVisibility('subscribe_form') {
     if (document.getElementById('bt1').value == 'Hide Layer') {
       document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'Show Layer';
       document.getElementById('subscribe_form').style.display = 'none';
     } else {
       document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'Hide Layer';
       document.getElementById('subscribe_form').style.display = 'block';
     }
   }
</script>
```

---

```
 <input type='button' name='type' id='bt1' value='Show Layer' onclick="setVisibility('subscribe_form');";>           
 <form action="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%/subscribe.php" method="post" id="subscribe_form" class="subscribe_form" name="subscribe_form">
```

Comment: Remove quotes `'` `function setVisibility(subscribe_form) {`

Comment: `function setVisibility('subscribe_form')` - your parameter is incorrectly delcared. Try removing the quotes around all of the `'subscribe_form'`s

Comment: The `language` attribute for the `<script />` tag is [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1). Use `type=text/javascript` instead.

Comment: I have done done this  function setVisibility(form) {
           form == 'subscribe_form';
           if(document.getElementById('bt1').value=='Hide Layer'){
           document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'Show Layer';
           document.getElementById(form).style.display = 'none';
           }else{
           document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'Hide Layer';
           document.getElementById(form).style.display = 'block'; but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Check the answer. In HTML5 you can use `<script>` tag which is easier to memorize during the learning process. Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MagXmr?editors=101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've written a string (`'subscribe_form'`) where there should be a variable name (`subscribe_form`) in your function declaration.  That, plus some other typos (`;` in the input tag, for one) are leading you astray.

Your [JavaScript console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) would have some messages about these errors.

A working version:

```js
function setVisibility(subscribe_form) {
  if (document.getElementById('bt1').value == 'Hide Layer') {
    document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'Show Layer';
    document.getElementById(subscribe_form).style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('bt1').value = 'Hide Layer';
    document.getElementById(subscribe_form).style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type='button' name='type' id='bt1' value='Show Layer' onclick="setVisibility('subscribe_form');" />
<form action="%%GLOBAL_ShopPath%%/subscribe.php" method="post" id="subscribe_form" class="subscribe_form" name="subscribe_form" style="display:none">
  <p>subscribe form</p>
</form>
```

Comment: ... or just Run Code Snippet above to see it working right here.

Comment: You'll need to show an example that *doesn't* work with corrected scripts. And is your Javascript Console showing any errors?

Comment: I put that code into my site and it doesn't do anything. Is it possible to DM/PM a link?

Comment: Nope. Still wondering if there are any [JavaScript console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers) errors.

Comment: @LMcNally you must include `<script>` and `</script>`. Check my edit for your post: http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/2058137

Comment: @belford The `<script>` tags were originally in the question. They were edited out by someone else since they're generally just clutter in SO questions. Check the edit history you linked to.

Comment: Sorry Paul, I thought I had said. No there are no Javascript errors. What I did find is that when I minimise my screen and the offcanvas menu appears, it works within the offcanvas menu. Just not in the top menu area on the desktop site.

Comment: Do those forms have the same ID? Are they on the same page? If so, only one of them will ever be affected by the script. HTML IDs must be unique within a page. Other than that, I'm just guessing and making things up without a (non-)working example in the question.

Comment: That's it. Thank you for your help Paul and everyone.

Comment: @LMcNally, you can mark an answer as accepted in order to show that it works for you. Check: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/302524. Best wishes.